# Prove that the reflection $z \mapsto \bar{z}$ is not a fractional linear transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm not sure how to prove $z \mapsto \bar{z}$ is not a fractional linear transformation.

I know complex conjugation is not an analytic map. All fractional linear transformations are. Thus, you will never find one representing a complex conjugation.

Is that right?

Comment: yes, analytic way from the pole ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Möbius transformations are analytic except at $T^{-1}(\infty)$.

Moreover they are all of the form $T(z)=\dfrac {az+b}{cz+d}, ad-bc\neq0$.

Thirdly,  conjugation isn't conformal.  For instance,  the angle between $1$ and $1+i$ is $\pi/4$.  But $1$ and $1-i$ are at an angle $-\pi/4$.